# Processing a large amount of querys and output in realtime

Tags: php, mysql, output

I need to find a way to output each row number of a large amount mysql querys in a textfield.

To find out which actual line of query the server process, I would like to output this row in realtime before the php script will tell the browser about his finish.

In my scenario, the browser shows any outputs only at the end of any scripts or,
by using `flush()`, delayed in block style to `x` rows.

How can I get this information in realtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your output in real time then you have to use ajax in your code. By using ajax you run your script with limit clasuse in mysql query you can show some record in fixed interval of time

i.e.

you can run your script after each 10 seconds to get your nest 10 records from mysql and append this record to your page.

this is not real time output but it is near to real time output

hope this will help you